# why does error cannot convert 'double*' to double show up in my cpp code

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

So here is the function I was writing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
double bin2dec(int binary[], int arr_size){
int x;
double y;
int a = 0;
double result_arr[1000];
while(binary[a] == 1 || binary[a] == 0){
    for(y = 0, x = 0; x <= arr_size; ++y, ++x){
        double result = binary[x] * pow(2, y);
        result_arr[x] = result;
    }
    ++a;
  }
return result_arr
}
```

What my function does is it converts binary to decimal
by taking in an integer array and array size it returns a double representing the output but
the problem is it says I can't convert 'double*' to 'double' error
when I execute it by including it in another file.

Comment: You are attempting to return an array of doubles from a function that is declared to return a single double. Although with that said you can't return this type of an array.

Comment: `return result_arr` - you are trying to return a C-style array which degrades to a pointer.  I'd suggest to *never* use C-style arrays and instead *always* use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: I am not sure why `result_arr` is an array of double in the first place.

Comment: `pow(2, y);` you should never use pow() with integers.

Comment: `x <= arr_size` is an  error because array indexes go from 0 to its size minus one in C and C++. So it should be `x < arr_size`.

Comment: `bin2dec` computers do not use decimal any more. Only very very old hardware uses floats with base 10. What really this `bin2dec` should do? Describe what end user should see after some action! This code is not salvageable. I suspect you what convert something to `std::string`, but your input is confusing too.

Comment: I'm still stuck on why `result_arr` even exists in the first place, and why the result type of this function is a `double` in the first place. If ever there was a question deserving of input and output elaboration, this is it. It should include an example of what you're expecting as the input argument data (the array content and length), and the expected resulting output. Right now this looks like you just started coding with multiple ideas in your head, and never settled on any single one of them.

Comment: Prefer to use `(x * x)` to `pow(2,x)`.  The multiplication uses a couple of assembly instructions.  The `pow` requires a function call and return.

Comment: Since you are using C++, prefer `std::bitset` to `int[]`.

Comment: The reason I made it a double is because the pow() function receives a double